# How implement a delegation pattern in c# using delegates?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, delegates, delegation

I want to implement delegation pattern using delegates

```cs
public class Cat {
    private delegate void SoundDelegate();
    private SoundDelegate sound;
    public Cat() {
        sound = new SoundDelegate(SomeClass.DoSound1);
    }
    public void DoSound() {
        sound();
    }
}
public class PussyCat {
    private delegate void SoundDelegate();
    private SoundDelegate sound;
    public PussyCat() {
        sound = new SoundDelegate(SomeClass.DoSound2);
    }
    public void DoSound() {
        sound();
    }
}
public class SomeClass {
    public static void DoSound1() {
        Console.WriteLine("Sound 1");
    }
    public static void DoSound2() {
        Console.WriteLine("Sound 2");
    }
}
```

Does this code impelement the delegation pattern? I mean can I use delegates for implement delegation pattern or this way is incorrect.

And if the previous example is correct and I can use delegates to implement the delegation pattern and implement the observer pattern, then what is the difference between the observer pattern and the delegation pattern and what is similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between delegation and observer patterns is a level of control your class has over the delegate/observer.
In case of delegate, it's assumed that your class has full control over how delegated class should be used. The observable class has no idea of how exactly it would be used by other classes.
It's also often assumed that observable class could have any number of observers while delegate is usually one.
I also simplified the code provided trying to avoid unnecessarily class PussyCat, so the original class could be configured to use any delegate in runtime.
You can also find CatObservable class to understand the idea of observable-observer implementation.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Cat cat1 = new Cat(SomeClass.DoSound1);
        Cat cat2 = new Cat(SomeClass.DoSound2);

        CatObservable cat3 = new CatObservable();
        cat3.Sound += Cat3_Sound;
        cat3.Sound += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { SomeClass.DoSound1(); } ;
        cat3.Sound += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { SomeClass.DoSound2(); };


    }

    private static void Cat3_Sound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Cat
{
    public delegate void SoundDelegate();
    public SoundDelegate Sound { get; set; }

    public Cat(SoundDelegate soundDelagate)
    {
        Sound = soundDelagate;
    }
    protected void DoSound()
    {
        if (Sound!=null)
            Sound();
    }
}

public class CatObservable
{
    public event EventHandler Sound;
    public CatObservable()
    {
    }
    protected void DoSound()
    {
        if (Sound != null)
            Sound(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public static void DoSound1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sound 1");
    }
    public static void DoSound2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sound 2");
    }
}
```

Comment: In delegation pattern context, can I say that the observed class delegates events to another class? Or it's incorrect?

Comment: I'd say it delegates logic to another class instead of events. And I'm not sure observed class is the right name for the delegate